# Line Buffered Cat

Tags: linux, line, cat

is there a way to do line-bufferd cat? For example, I want to watch a UART device, and I only want to see it's message when there is a whole line. Can I do some thing like:

```
cat --line-buffered /dev/crbif0rb0c0ttyS0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but GNU grep with `--line-buffered` can do this. Just search for something every line has, such as `'^'`.

Comment: I tried `cat /dev/crbif0rb0c0ttyS0 | grep . --line-buffered`, but only empty lines are printed. If I substitute the UART device with a normal file, then it's OK. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Oh, I tried `cat /dev/crbif0rb0c0ttyS0 | grep ^ --line-buffered`, and this works! Don't know why though...

Comment: This works but can you explain? cat's output supposed to be buffered since it is connected to a pipe. So how the grep's --line-buffered couses the cat's buffer to flush in order for grep to operate as line-buffered?

Comment: "cat's output supposed to be buffered since it is connected to a pipe." [citation needed]

Comment: I came across this while doing a little research about stdio buffers. There is [this](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) article, and I in many situations is being mentioned that _...By pretending to be a terminal, the buffering of stdout is automatically set to 'line mode, otherwise it is set to buffered (4KB usually)...'_. I am not sure though, so if you could please give some technical reference about stdout, stdin, etc buffering behavior along with pipes, it would be very helpful. Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

You can also use bash to your advantage here:

```
cat /dev/crbif0rb0c0ttyS0 | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

Since the `read` command reads a line at a time, it will perform the line buffering that `cat` does not.

Comment: There's no need for `cat` if you're using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it through perl in a no-op line-buffered mode:

```
perl -pe 1 /dev/whatever
```