# make stdin unbufferd for long lines in console ... cat > textfile

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, posix, stdin, cat

maybe a peculiar question, but

I came across an odd result when pasting through `cat` into a text file (`cat > textfile` and signaling *EOF* by Ctrl+D when done ) on ubuntu linux.
It turns out the **stdin line buffer** prevents lines **exceeding 4k** (see [Line Buffered Cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443704/line-buffered-cat))

Neither the options of [gnu cat](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cat-invocation.html#cat-invocation) (vs. [posix cat](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/cat/)) nor usage of [stdbuf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html#stdbuf-invocation) (`stdbuf -i0 -o0 cat > textfile`) resulted in files exceeding 4k.

Obviously I am doing something wrong, since `cat` does stdout these kind of files when created with nano or vim quite fine.

I would really like to keep using this convenient way of creating files on the fly or pipeing in to other commands from cli without that limitation.

Thank you

Version: cat (GNU coreutils) 8.28

Edit: it obviously is not cat itself but the way the stdin is buffered in the terminal, however vim and nano manage to switch it of
(see also [Disable buffering for stdin and stdout using setvbuf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365655/disable-buffering-for-stdin-and-stdout-using-setvbuf))

Comment: I suspect the limitation has nothing to do with cat, but is an issue with the terminal buffer.

Comment: I suspected this too, thats why i tried this out with nano and vim both have the same terminal interface

Comment: `vim` doesn't use the terminal buffer.  It puts the terminal in raw mode.  I suspect nano does the same.

Comment: so the solution would be to somehow disable terminal buffer ... *sigh* i tried that

Comment: This might be a starting point to find out, which clipboard implementation you are using: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254740/who-stores-copy-paste-buffers-in-x11

Comment: @ceving the clipboard content is transferred to the terminal just fine ... it is only that the terminal is forcing a buffer ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/19395600/3623574

Answer (score 0):

There is no buffer which clips lines.

Example:

```
$ { for i in {1..4096}; do printf x; done; echo y; } | cat > data
```

The file contains 4098 bytes: 4096 times x, one y and a new-line character.

```
$ stat -c %s data
4098
```

And it has exactly one line.

```
$ wc -l data
1 data
```

Comment: what does tell you that there is no flush after each print?

Comment: but good idea i have  modified your script a little to verify that it is a correct assumption that cat does not use a buffer (as I assumed when i used it and ran into this pitfall) `z="";  for i in {1..4096}; do z="${z}x"; done; echo "${z}yz" | cat > /tmp/thisshouldwork.txt ; wc /tmp/thisshouldwork.txt`

Comment: @Summer-Sky Such a "flush" of pipes does not exist. It exists [`fsync`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43188944/402322) but if works only for files and not for pipes. And a pipe buffer is bigger than 4k: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer

Comment: not sure how that can be (every buffer should have a flush) but it is ruled out anyway ... 
However seeing that this cat in itself does NOT use a buffered std in the first place makes it even more peculiar

Comment: @Summer-Sky: In your case `cat` has a **tty** for input, in this answer it is a **pipe**.  Seeing different buffering behavior is not surprising.

Comment: @ceving: Your test is invalid, you'd need to pass the data through a pseudo-tty in order to test `cat` in the same scenario OP has.

Comment: @BenVoigt you are also correct that somehow the tty is the issue here. using unbuffer for pipe uncoupling like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910661/pretend-to-be-a-tty-in-bash-for-any-command#32981392

`z="";  for i in {1..4096}; do z="${z}x"; done; echo "${z}yzzzzyyyzzz" | unbuffer -p  cat > /tmp/thisshouldwork.txt ; wc /tmp/thisshouldwork.txt`